# Map versus FlatMap on String

Tags: scala, dictionary

Listening to the Collections lecture from [Functional Programming Principles in Scala](https://www.coursera.org/course/progfun), I saw this example:

```
scala> val s = "Hello World"

scala> s.flatMap(c => ("." + c)) // prepend each element with a period
res5: String = .H.e.l.l.o. .W.o.r.l.d
```

Then, I was curious why Mr. Odersky didn't use a `map` here. But, when I tried map, I got a different result than I expected.

```
scala> s.map(c => ("." + c))
res8: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(.H, .e, .l, .l, .o, 
                                                          ". ", .W, .o, .r, .l,
```

I expected that above call to return a String, since I'm `map`-ing, i.e. applying a function to each item in the "sequence," and then returning a new "sequence."

However, I could perform a `map` rather than `flatmap` for a `List[String]`:

```
scala> val sList = s.toList
sList: List[Char] = List(H, e, l, l, o,  , W, o, r, l, d)

scala> sList.map(c => "." + c)
res9: List[String] = List(.H, .e, .l, .l, .o, ". ", .W, .o, .r, .l, .d)
```

Why was a `IndexedSeq[String]` the return type of calling `map` on the String?

Comment: Because you can't put two characters in single Char type? And character + character is two characters that produce String type.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that, in order to apply "map" to a String, Scala treats the string as a sequence of chars (`IndexedSeq[String]`). This is what you get as a result of the map invocation, where for each element of said sequence, the operation is applied. Since Scala treated the string as a sequence to apply `map`, that is what `map`returns.

`flatMap` then simply invokes `flatten` on that sequence afterwards, which then "converts" it back to a String

Comment: how am i supposed to guess without looking at implementation or trying it out that `string` map converts it to `IndexSeq[String]` and that `flatten` converts it back to `String`.  it sounds to me like every time I will apply `map` or `flatMap` to some data structure in scala I'll need to try it out or look at it's implementation to understand it's behaviour, is that the case? if so is this a good design (clear code wise)?

Answer (score 18):

You also have an interesting "[collection of Scala flatMap examples](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/collection-scala-flatmap-examples-map-flatten)", the first of which illustrates that difference between `flatMap` and `map`:

```
scala> val fruits = Seq("apple", "banana", "orange")
fruits: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(apple, banana, orange)

scala> fruits.map(_.toUpperCase)
res0: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE)

scala> fruits.flatMap(_.toUpperCase)
res1: Seq[Char] = List(A, P, P, L, E, B, A, N, A, N, A, O, R, A, N, G, E)
```

> Quite a difference, right?
>   Because `flatMap` treats a `String` as a sequence of `Char`, it flattens the resulting list of strings into a sequence of characters (`Seq[Char]`).
>   `flatMap` is a combination of `map` and `flatten`, so it first runs `map` on the sequence, then runs `flatten`, giving the result shown.
>
> You can see this by running map and then flatten yourself:

```
scala> val mapResult = fruits.map(_.toUpperCase)
mapResult: Seq[String] = List(APPLE, BANANA, ORANGE)

scala> val flattenResult = mapResult.flatten
flattenResult: Seq[Char] = List(A, P, P, L, E, B, A, N, A, N, A, O, R, A, N, G, E)
```

Comment: Hi @VonC I was trying examples that are their in the link that you shared. For below examples as shown on his blog he is able to get results for the below examples but when I am trying to run it I am getting Number Format Exception for String "foo" when I am trying to apply `toInt` function.
`scala> val strings = Seq("1", "2", "foo", "3", "bar")`
`strings: Seq[java.lang.String] = List(1, 2, foo, 3, bar)`

`scala> strings.map(toInt)`
`res0: Seq[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(3), None)`

`scala> strings.flatMap(toInt)`
`res1: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)`

Comment: @Novice Interesting. That would be best as a question on its own for others to test it out.

Comment: `Because flatMap treats a String as a sequence of Char` how am i supposed to guess that? by trying it out? by looking at it's implementation?

Comment: @Jas I agree. https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-scala/9781449368814/ch07.html gives a clue, describing the  Sequence types, and listing String(!) in it: "In Scala String is a valid collection just like the others. A “string” derives its name, after all, from being a string of characters, in this case a sequence of Char elements. The String type is an immutable collection, extending Iterable and supporting its operations, while also serving as a wrapper for Java strings and supporting such java.lang.String operations as split and trim."

Answer (score 7):

Your map function `c => ("." + c)` takes a char and returns a String. It's like taking a List and returning a List of Lists. flatMap flattens that back.

If you would return a char instead of a String you wouldn't need the result flattened, e.g. `"abc".map(c => (c + 1).toChar)` returns "bcd".

Answer (score 1):

With `map` you are taking a list of characters and turning it into a list of strings. That's the result you see. A `map` never changes the length of a list – the list of strings has as many elements as the original string has characters.

With `flatMap` you are taking a list of characters and turning it into a list of strings and *then you mush those strings together into a single string again*. `flatMap` is useful when you want to turn one element in a list into multiple elements, without creating a list of lists. (This of course also means that the resulting list can have any length, including 0 – this is not possible with `map` unless you start out with the empty list.)

Answer (score 0):

Use flatMap in situations where you run *map* followed by *flattern*. The specific situation is this:

• You’re using *map* (or a *for/yield* expression) to create a new collection from an existing collection.

• The resulting collection is a List of Lists.

• You call *flatten* immediately after *map* (or a *for/yield* expression).

When you’re in this situation, you can use flatMap instead.

Example: Add all the Integers from the bag

```
val bag = List("1", "2", "three", "4", "one hundred seventy five")

def toInt(in: String): Option[Int] = {
try {
Some(Integer.parseInt(in.trim))
} catch {
case e: Exception => None
}
}
```

Using a flatMap method

```
> bag.flatMap(toInt).sum
```

Using map method (3 steps needed)

```
bag.map(toInt) // List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(1), Some(2), None, Some(4), None)

bag.map(toInt).flatten //List[Int] = List(1, 2, 4)

bag.map(toInt).flatten.sum //Int = 7
```