# Why do .map.flatten and flatMap on a Scala Map return different results?

Tags: scala

I heard many people say `flatMap` is similar to `map` + `flatten`. For example, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209558/8170655).

> Quite a difference, right?
>   Because `flatMap` treats a `String` as a sequence of `Char`, it flattens the resulting list of strings into a sequence of characters (`Seq[Char]`).
>   `flatMap` is a combination of `map` and `flatten`, so it first runs `map` on the sequence, then runs `flatten` giving the result shown.

But I have some code problems today. The result of `map` and `flatMap` seems to be different. Here are my code

```
object ListDemo {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val map1 = Map("a" -> List(1 ->11,1->111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22, 2 ->222)).map(_._2).flatten
    val map2 = Map("a" -> List(1 ->11,1->111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22, 2 ->222)).flatMap(_._2)
    map1.foreach(println)
    println()
    map2.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

the result is not expected.

```
(1,11)
(1,111)
(2,22)
(2,222)

(1,111)
(2,222)
```

Why it happened?

Comment: they are compatible only if a given function to `map` returns same type `T[_]`. call class `A`'s `map` and class `B`'s flatten might be different result from calling `A`'s `flatMap`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When calling `.map(f)` on a `Map` with an `f` that returns `(K, V)` for some K and V (not necessarily the same K and V types of the original `Map`), the result will be a `Map[K, V]`. Otherwise, if `f` returns some other (non-pair) type `T`, the result will be an `Iterable[T]`. So it will be a `Map` if the function returns a pair and an `Iterable` otherwise.

In your case the function returns `List[(Int, Int)]`, so the result is an `Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]]` - not a Map. The `.flatten` then turns this into an `Iterable[(Int, Int)]`.

When using `flatMap` directly, you directly end up with the `(Int, Int)` pairs, so the result will be a `Map[Int, Int]` - not an `Iterable[(Int, Int)]`. And since `Map`s don't allow duplicate keys, the `Map` contains less elements than the `Iterable`.

Comment: why aren't `(1,11)` and `(2,22)`?

Comment: @genius-pig because they get "overwritten" in the map by `111` and `222`, which have the same key

Comment: @genius-pig You mean why is the result `Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)` instead of `Map(1 -> 11, 2 -> 22)`? Because `1 -> 111` and `2 -> 222` come later in the list and thus override the earlier values for those keys.

Comment: @sepp2k Isn't this case totally different from the definition of `flatMap` and `map(f).flatten` relationship (this is more of a Monad composition case and we all know that Monads don't compose), so even without considering special property of `Map` we can not expect the equality to hold.

Answer (score 1):

You are kind of misunderstanding things here,

So, Lets say you have `x: M[A]` and `f: A = N[B]`for any `Monad` `M` and `N` then `x.flatMap(f)` should be same as `x.map(f).flatten`.

But what you have here is kind of a nested monad `map: M[N[A]]` and your function is `f: A => B` with following aliasing,

```
scala> type MapWithStringKey[A] = Map[String, A]
// defined type alias MapWithStringKey

scala> type TupleOfInt = (Int, Int)
// defined type alias TupleOfInt

scala> val map: MapWithStringKey[List[TupleOfInt]] = Map("a" -> List(1 ->11,1->111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22, 2 ->222))
// map: MapWithStringKey[List[TupleOfInt]] = Map(a -> List((1,11), (1,111)), b -> List((2,22), (2,222)))
```

This case is entirely different from above mentioned standard definition which connects `flatMap` to `map` and `flatten`.

Now, It is just one of the non-standards cases where you can choose to use either of the two choices depending on what you want. And when we add the special key-uniqueness properties of `Map` (which is already discussed in answer by @sepp2k), things become even more unpredictable.

Answer (score 1):

TL;DR: the result type of both calls is different. The call to `.map().flatten` returns a `Iterable[(Int, Int)]` and the call to `.flatMap()` returns a `Map[Int, Int]`. Since a map may not contain the same key twice, the first entry per key is overwritten by the second entry.

Consider a `Map` as a `Iterable[(Key,Value)]`. When calling `.map`, you will have to provide it a function that returns a tuple, `(Key, Value)` (the actual types may be different from the original `Key` and `Value`).

In your example, `Value` happens to be a `List[(Int, Int)]`. When calling `.map`, and returning the `Value` of the original `Map`, you end up with a `Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]]`, which your call to `.flatten` turns into a `Iterable[(Int, Int)]` by concatenating the 'inner' lists together. If you were to turn *that* into a map (by calling `.toMap`), you would see the same result as with `flatMap`.

Now, `flatMap` is different in that it expects a return type of `Seq[(Key, Value)]`, rather than just `(Key, Value)`. It then uses the returned value as the entries in a newly constructed `Map`.

In your case, your original `Value` of `List[(Int, Int)]` satisfies the expected return type, converting you original `Map[(String, List[(Int, Int)]` into a `Map[(Int, Int)]`. Since a map cannot contain two entries with the same keys, the second occurrence of the key replaces the earlier occurrence.

To see this behavior, it helps to use the REPL (just run `scala`) instead of writing a main class, so you can see the intermediate values and their types.

```
scala> val theMap = Map("a" -> List(1 ->11,1->111), "b" -> List(2 -> 22, 2 ->222))
theMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,List[(Int, Int)]] = Map(a -> List((1,11), (1,111)), b -> List((2,22), (2,222)))

scala> val mapped = theMap.map(_._2)
mapped: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[List[(Int, Int)]] = List(List((1,11), (1,111)), List((2,22), (2,222)))

scala> val flattened = mapped.flatten
flattened: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[(Int, Int)] = List((1,11), (1,111), (2,22), (2,222))

scala> val flatMapped = theMap.flatMap(_._2)
flatMapped: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)

scala> val flattenedToMap = flattened.toMap
flattenedToMap: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(1 -> 111, 2 -> 222)
```